# How do I refresh a form with a timer?

Tags: c#, forms, refresh

I use this code to refresh my from it work good for one time after that the timer stopped with me

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer1.Interval = 900000;//5 minutes
        timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(Timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Start();
    }
    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do whatever you want 
        RefreshMyForm();
    }
    private void RefreshMyForm()
    {
        this.Hide();
        Graph1 graph = new Graph1();
        graph.Show();

    }
```

i don't know what i miss in this code 
it hide the from and didn't open again
**start refresh that what i looking form**
[image]

Comment: Every time you click `Button1` you're reattaching the event to `Tick`.

Comment: @mjwills i want it to close the form and open new open

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria so what should i do ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the timer deceleration out of the button click and make it "global" to the class. Also, set it up on the Form_Load (make sure you wire up the Form_Load method to your Form_Load event.

Also, your hide logic is a bit faulty. You hide the form, then create a graph (but don't attach it to the Form) then show it. Added some comments below to help you navigate these issues.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
     timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
     timer1.Interval = 900000;//5 minutes
     timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(Timer1_Tick);
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    if (!timer1.Enabled)
        timer1.Start();
}

private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do whatever you want 
     RefreshMyForm();
}


private void RefreshMyForm()
{    
    // Do your data update logic here   
    this.Refresh();       
}
```

Comment: sorry bro bout it open another form every time it mack refresh on it

Comment: Is that what you want it to do? What is the behaviour you expect?

Comment: i want it close the first from and open the new one with refresh @Murray

Comment: Updated the answer. This will hide the main form (on the first refresh), show the graph form and refresh it. On subsequent refreshed the graph will just refresh since the main for is already hidden.

Comment: my bro sorry the main from is the graph form is the same

Comment: Updated the answer, then you just need to refresh "this". Make sure Refresh method has the right logic  in it.

Comment: Added a comment where you need to put your update logic to make changes to your graphs.  See: // Do your data update logic here